# Jupyter Notebook "image" output vs Pycharm

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm

```
from binarytree import build

inp = [4, 2, 5, 1, 3, None, 6]
root = build(inp)
```

I have the above code in Jupyter Notebook.  I can either print the root or just type root in a cells and they both give different outputs:

[image]

If I go to PyCharm, I cannot get the "image" as in Jupyter Notebook.  So I would like to ask how does Jupyter Notebook handle the output from root to produce a "image" and how can I replicate it in PyCharm ?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Relevant section of the binarytree docs: [Graphviz and Jupyter Notebook](https://binarytree.readthedocs.io/en/main/graphviz.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can find in the [documentation for binary tree](https://binarytree.readthedocs.io/en/main/graphviz.html) it uses [graphviz](https://pypi.org/project/graphviz/) for displaying graphs in jupyter notebooks. So to emulate the same results you can install `graphviz` and then do something like

```py
from binarytree import build

inp = [4, 2, 5, 1, 3, None, 6]
root = build(inp)

graph = root.graphviz ()
graph.format = 'png'
graph.render ('output', view=True)
```

to display the graph as an image using your system image viewer

Comment: Oh.  ic.  I thought it's a Jupyter functionality.  Cause it will display the output of a function but Pycharm will not.  I thought it's something to do with Jupyter Notebook.  So it's from the binary tree implementation.  ok.  I get it.  Thanks very much !!!